# Display COUNT in Jtable

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I'm working on an eclipse interface or sorting by certain sql statements. I'm currently doing one for COUNT of number of review comments based on distinct video names. The statement executes correctly in mysql workbench, but I receive no output in eclipse. I am using the same Jtable for 3 others sql statements and I receive and output for them when I run them through eclipse. Can COUNT not be displayed in a Jtable or am I missing something in my code? The full code is rather length so I am adding the part with only the COUNT statement and my table. I'm not receiving an errors, there's simply no output upon button click. Thank you

```
JButton btnCount = new JButton("Most Comments");
        btnCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{ "review_comments", "video_name"}, 0);

                try {

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdatabase", "root", "pass1234");
                            Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                            String sql = "SELECT video_name, COUNT(DISTINCT review_comments) FROM review GROUP BY video_name ORDER BY review_comments ASC";



                            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                // handle row 

                            {


                                 String i = rs.getString("review_comments");
                                 String a = rs.getString("video_name");



                                 model.addRow(new Object[]{i, a});
                                    table.setModel(model);

                                    }
                            }
                            {

                            con.close();}
                    } catch(Exception e) {System.out.print (e);}



            }
     });
        btnCount.setBounds(20, 603, 130, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCount);
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT review_comments) as review_comments`? (It's bit of guess on my part - alternatively, you could use `rs.getString(1)` and `rs.getString(2)` instead of using the column names)

Comment: That actually worked exactly like I wanted. Thank you!